# add a column based on the value in a certain column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to manpulate my dataframe, however, I searched for the answer for a while without a solution. If this question duplicated, I sincerely apologize to this.

I have a dataframe(df) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': ['Emo/3', 'Emo/4', 'Emo/1', '', 'Neu/5', 'Neu/2'],
        'Height': [5.1, 6.2, 5.1,'', 5.2, 5.2],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    A       Height
0   Emo/3   5.1
1   Emo/4   6.2
2   Emo/1   5.1
3       
4   Neu/5   5.2
5   Neu/2   5.2
```

I want add another column "B", so that the value of the "B" is based on column"A". If a row of column A contains a certain string the same row in column B will be a number: eg. if "Emo/" in column A, then column B is 0. If the row in column is empty, then colmn B in the same row is also empty. The output should looks like this:

```
    A      Height   B
0   Emo/3   5.1     0
1   Emo/4   6.2     0
2   Emo/1   5.1     0
3           
4   Neu/5   5.2     1
5   Neu/2   5.2     1
```

Currently, I have the code below, but it gives me an error message: "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable"

```
df["B"]=""
for index, row in df.iterrows:
  if "Emo/" in row["A"]:
    row["B"]=0
  elif "Neu/" in row['A']:
    row['B']=1
  elif row['A']=="":
    row['B']=""
```

Any suggestions helps! Thanks!

Comment: Could this be a version issue? I'm using pandas 1.3.1 and if I use `df.iterrows()` instead of `df.iterrows`, this works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [zlipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4738478/zlipp) commented, parentheses are missing in the method call:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
#                            ^^
```

---

**However, note that [`iterrows` should be avoided whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/13138364).**

I suggest using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). Build the conditions with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (or [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)) and set `default=''`:

```
conditions = [
    df['A'].str.contains('Emo/'),
    df['A'].str.contains('Neu/'),
]
choices = [
    0,
    1,
]

df['B'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='')
#        A Height  B
# 0  Emo/3    5.1  0
# 1  Emo/4    6.2  0
# 2  Emo/1    5.1  0
# 3                 
# 4  Neu/5    5.2  1
# 5  Neu/2    5.2  1
```

Comment: Thank u so very to point that out. This methods works. Though I found out that I need an additional argument for the pandas dataframe, probably due to my python version (3.8). ```conditions = [
    df['A'].str.contains('Emo/'), na=False
    df['A'].str.contains('Neu/'), na=False
]```